# O que é a tecnologia CDI?

Tags: injeção-de-dependência, cdi, java

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação web e um colega da universidade que está alguns  períodos além do que eu estou cursando disse que usando o CDI teria uma melhor performance, entretanto, ate o momento ainda não tinha ouvido falar desse termo.
Gostaria de um exemplo simples de seu uso para se ter uma ideia de como o CDI é usado em uma aplicação web.

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/cdi/info

Comment: @VictorStafusa você podia responder a pergunta cara!! Dei uma editada no fim da mesma!!Obrigado pela atenção!!

Comment: [Clique aqui para ver alguns resultados no SOpt](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=injeção+dependência+java)

Comment: @PenaPintada É porque eu não achei que isso seria uma boa resposta. De qualquer forma, a sua pergunta ficou bem melhor agora. :)

Answer (score 1):

CDI é a especificação do Java EE 6 que cuida da parte de injeção de dependências. Pra se interar melhor no assunto de uma lida em http://blog.caelum.com.br/use-cdi-no-seu-proximo-projeto-java/

Comment: Obrigado cara, mas  você poderia responder com suas palavras o conteúdo desse link! Ai a sua resposta seria considerada como a resposta final para essa humilde pergunta!